# Json dentro de otro json con objetos c# NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#, json

Deseo formar un json con el siguiente formato:

```
{
"pos" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa",
"fecha_emision": "01/11/2011",
"tipo_documento": "FAC",
"documento": "001-001-0000080100",
"estado": "P",
"electronico" : true,
"autorizacion": "",
"caja_id": 5,
"cliente": {
    "ruc": "0922054366001",
    "cedula": "0922054366",
    "razon_social": "Nombres del Cliente",
    "telefonos": "0988800001",
    "direccion": "Direccion cliente",
    "tipo": "N",
    "email": "cliente@fico.com",
    "es_extranjero": false
}
}
```

Estoy utilizando NewtonSoft.Json en c# pero cuando ingreso la primera parte del json la libreria ingresa los {   }  al inicio y fin y no puedo ingresar ya nada dentro dentro json :

```
{
   "pos":"448646.4545-45-",
   "fecha_emision":"11/01/2020",
   "tipo_documento":"FAC",
   "documento":"001-001-00000045",
   "estado":"P",
   "electronico":"true",
   "autorizacion":"",
   "caja_id":null
}
```

Mi clase:

```
 class Documento
{

    public string pos,fecha_emision,tipo_documento,documento,estado,electronico,autorizacion,caja_id;

    public Documento(string pos, string fecha_emision, string tipo_documento, string documento, string estado, string electronico, string autorizacion, string caja_id)
    {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.fecha_emision = fecha_emision;
        this.tipo_documento = tipo_documento;
        this.documento = documento;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.electronico = electronico;
        this.autorizacion = autorizacion;
        this.caja_id = caja_id;
    }
}
```

Y dentro de esa clase quiero ingresar esta clase :

```
   class Cliente
{

    public string ruc, cedula, razon_social, telefonos, direccion, tipo, email, es_extranjero;

    public Cliente(string ruc, string cedula, string razon_social, string telefonos, string direccion, string tipo, string email, string es_extranjero)
    {
        this.ruc = ruc;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.razon_social = razon_social;
        this.telefonos = telefonos;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.email = email;
        this.es_extranjero = es_extranjero;
    }
}
```

Mostrarlo en formato Json.

Comment: A tu clase documento agregale la propiedad cliente

Comment: como lo estas serializando tu objeto?

Comment: Como te ha comentado @Manny , deberías enseñarnos el código donde haces la serialización.

Comment: Gracias Miguel Zarate, lo resolvi de la manera que dijiste.

Comment: recuerda siempre: escribir en mayúsculas == gritar. Evita generar bulla cuando publiques preguntas :)

Answer (score 0):

A tu clase `Documento` agregale la propiedad cliente.

```
public Cliente cliente {get; set;}
```

Le asignas el valor antes de serializarlo.